# Navigation Bar not showing in Storyboard in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I know this question has been asked before. I have already tried this [Navigation Bar not showing in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609686/navigation-bar-not-showing-in-storyboard). I have a navigation bar and a toolbar. They were showing in the storyboard fine before I restarted my system. They work completely fine during runtime but I am no longer able to access it using Storyboard. I have also tried changing top bar for Simulated metrics. Here is the screenshot for the same.

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

[image: Runtime Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a segue connected to it from a controller which is linked to a UINavigationController or a link to it making it the root of a UINavigationController? Sometimes you need this for it to show up in storyboard.

Comment: Just noticed you added your own navigation bar. Is this so you can use it in modal presentations? If you intend pushing this controller, then you should use the navigation bar which comes with a UINavigationController and only set the controllers navigation item. Aside from that my other assumption would be you might have your constraints wrong. Top of the nav bar should be constrained to the top layout guide and the top of table to the bottom of the navigation bar. Looks like the table thinks it can go over the top of your nav bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This seems like your frame is misplaced from the top and not according to the constraint too
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure it is ticked here for Navigation Controller in Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this option is still available in xcode 7.2 +

Comment: I still see it in 7.3.1. It is in the navigation bar view controller screen.